# How to draw a line using the equation: y=mx + c in java

Tags: java, javafx, jframe, line

I would like to draw a line using the equation of a line which basically gives a slope/gradient and the y intercept "c"
I've tried to draw the line using two points using

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
}
```

but i would like to draw a line using the equation instead.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? You pick `x1` (start) and `x2` (end) and based on your formula you should be able to calculate `y1` and `y2`.

Answer (score 0):

Just assume some values of x - `xa` and `xb`. Plug it into the equation to calculate y for them, e.g.

```
g.drawLine(xa, m*xa + c, xb, m*xb + c)
```